# File upload works during debugging but not on the actual run in c#

Tags: c#, file-upload, selenium, selenium-webdriver, opacity

While debugging, the below code works. But when I get it to do a trial run of the test it displays an error. To combat the error, I've added a java script ( example from another question) to change the opacity, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

**Upload part of the code:**

```
//File Details
 FileName = "EMED.pdf";

 FilePath = "\\\\iasfs1\\QA\\OpenSpace\\Automation\\FilesForUpload\\EMED.pdf";

//File Upload
WaitForElementPresent(By.Id("upload"));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('FileUpload').style.opacity = 1;");''

IWebElement fileUpload = driver.FindElement(By.Id("FileUpload"));
Console.Write("fileUpload.Displayed : " + fileUpload.Displayed.ToString());
Debug.WriteLine("fileUpload.Displayed : " + fileUpload.Displayed.ToString());
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("fileUpload.Displayed : " +       fileUpload.Displayed.ToString());

fileUpload.SendKeys(OSData.FilePath);'
```

**Error displayed**
    Message: OpenQA.Selenium.ElemenyNotVisibleException : Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with.

Any help on the above will be appreciated

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which line throws the error? Is it the `FindElement(By.Id("FileUpload"))`?

Comment: Yes thats the one that threw up errors

Comment: How come you're dealing with two different elements; on line 7 you wait for an element to be present, with id `"upload"` but then on line 11 you try to find a different element, with id `"FileUpload"` - is that deliberate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said it works on Debugging, but not on a full run through?

99% of the times this happens, it is because of a waiting issue.

You are waiting for the element to be present but not waiting for it to be visible, which explains the error (NotVisibleException).  Try waiting for the element to be visible.

Comment: Upvote to @MrTi. But, it's a kind of tricky fileupload, so I would really use js to set needed value.

Comment: Thank you for that, I've added a Thread.Sleep(10000) and that seems to be working intermittently. I'll try other values and report back

Alexander: What js can I use? I'm not well in that area.

Comment: Look at this document on different ways to wait.  Thread.Sleep() is probably the worst form of waiting. http://assertselenium.com/2013/01/29/webdriver-wait-commands/

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `SendKeys` try to set the needed value with js

Comment: An example of the js will be appreciated.

Comment: That might work, if the element is not visible; but why should that be necessary? The test is supposed to replicating normal user actions i.e. interacting with visible elements.

Comment: @user2471464 Please, post the full tag content of IWebElement fileUpload